# Assign role of db_denydatawriter to user dbo

Tags: sql-server, dbo

When I try to do this I receive the following error message:

> Add member failed for DatabaseRole 'db_denydatawriter'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>   Cannot use the reserved user or role name 'dbo'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15405)

I have a database that needs to remain 'frozen'.  **I want to maintain ownership of the database**, but prevent myself (as dbo) from accidentally modifying the data.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

---

EDIT:  I've decided to open a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209363/make-data-in-database-read-only-but-allow-schema-changes) to address the lines below: 

<strike>The data in the database needs to remain frozen.  However, the structure might change.</strike>

The database is actually several databases.  They are essentially snapshots of the production database taken semi-annually.  Users are then able to view historical data by switching the back-end database from the front-end GUI.  However, sometimes new fields get added to the tables in the current database.  This can cause problems if the front-end expects these fields to be present.  Our current solution is to add the fields on the fly (users have db_datareader, db_denydatawriter, and db_ddladmin roles).  What this means is that the database cannot be made read-only because that would prevent changes to the table structure.

Comment: When the current db structure changes, is it a controlled change by the dba or a developer? If so, then just turn off the read only flags, make your changes to the snapshot dbs, and turn the flags back on.

Comment: I could do that, but the snapshot is large enough that it takes nearly a full minute to switch the flag.  Appending the field to a table in the non-read-only db takes at most a couple of seconds.  From a performance standpoint, switching the flag off and on is not feasible.

Comment: How often does this happen? Is two minutes of down-time on a snapshot a big problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the db to read only:

ALTER DATABASE [db_name] SET  READ_ONLY